PHP Laravel Eloquent ORM. How to test table relantionship (belongsToMany)
I'm currently building an API assigned for an ecommerce project using Laravel framework. While getting help to build data migrations and Models, I got confused on how the product_categories, the intermediate table, can link a product and category as in the many to many relantionship (products <-> product_categories <-> category). These are the models in development:

This is the category class:
class Category extends Model
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Product::class,
            ProductCategory::class,
        );
    }
}

And the product Model
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'price',
        'active',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'price' => 'float',
        'active' => 'boolean',
    ];


    public function categories() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Category::class,
            ProductCategory::class
        );
    }

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            OrderItem::class,
        );
    }
}

As I'm still new at this I couldn't understand from the documentation what makes a product and category be linked neither how the Order Model should look like.
I'm using postman to make requests and they work with the current controllers. So my doubt is actually conceptual instead of technique.

You can create a simple controller like the one below:
public function index()
{
    $product = Product::with('categories')->get();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $product
    ]);
}

From the code above, all related data for each product category should be retrieved. If you are using Eloquent, you don't need to perform joins, which will make the process more time-efficient.

That helped, but I'm still looking for the controller to link product to category. There is a pivot table ProductCategory, should I make a controller for that class or just make attachment methods for both product and category controllers?

Create a controller according to your needs, for example, if you want to create a controller for products that display all categories of that product, with the example controller I provided.

Just remove ProductCategory::class from both the relations as laravel will automatically look for the pivot table category_product
